# Как менять proxy в selenium на каждой итерации цикла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

```
def start():
  for i in range(3):
    make_request('https://www.google.com/search?q=работа', i)

user_agents = [
  'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
     Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Moto G (4)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
     Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
     Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36',
]

proxies = [
  '95.141.193.14:80',
  '95.141.193.35:80',
  '212.120.186.39:60963',
]

def make_request(url, index):
  try:
      user_agent = user_agents[index]
  except IndexError:
      user_agent = user_agents[0]

  try:
      proxy = proxies[index]
  except IndexError:
      proxy = proxies[0]

  options = Options()
  # меняем user-agent
  options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
  # игнор ошибок
  options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')

  webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
      'httpProxy': proxy,
      'ftpProxy': proxy,
      'sslProxy': proxy,
      'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
  }
  webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['acceptSslCerts'] = True

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, chrome_options=options)

  driver.get(url)

  # закрываем браузер
  driver.close()
  driver.quit()
```

При первом запросе все работает, но при втором запросе, когда я меняю прокси, в консоль ide выпадает ошибка: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED`
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: может, со вторым прокси что-то не так?

Comment: Менял их местами и получал такой же результат.

Comment: вместо chrome_options=options попробуйте options=options?

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.